# Print lines with numbers infront

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I am currently trying to print a list of objects where each new line gets a number infront of it. Like the first line has a 1 infront of it, the second has a 2 etc. 
The print function works fine when I am not using the numbers for each line.

I tried to write it:

```
n=0
for x in List:
   print("\n".join(str(n,x))
   n+=1
```

The List in this case contains a bunch of objects, all having 4 attributes, self.name, self.randomint, self.randomint2, self.randomint3

But I am getting an invalid syntax doing this, would appreciate help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are unbalanced in the following line:

```
   print("\n".join(str(n,x))
```

Replace it with:

```
   print("\n".join(str(n,x)))
   #                        ^
```

Another issue: `str` accepts only one argument.

```
>>> str(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
>>> str(1)
'1'
```

---

Complete example code:

```
n=0
for x in List:
    print(n, x)
    n += 1
```

using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions#enumerate):

```
for n, x in enumerate(List, 1):
    print(n, x)
```

Comment: Looks like they want `enumerate`

Comment: Since it is an object, I have to use the str() function in order to print it, trying to use one of your methods it gives me the error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found --- how do I go about solving this? :

Comment: @user2982959, Could you show the full traceback. (by editing your question). It will be good to show what `List` contains.

Comment: @user2982959, Try `print(n, str(x))`.

Comment: TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: @user2982959, Why don't use `print(n, str(x))` ?  (`print n, str(x))` if you use Python 2.x)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a closing parenthesis:

```
print("\n".join(str(n,x))
#                --------^
```

but that's not a correct statement still as `str()` takes one string argument with optional encoding.

It'll be easier to use `enumerate()` to add a count, and pass in two arguments to `print()`:

```
for n, x in enumerate(Line):
    print(n, x)
```